# Multi-mapping a value while saving intermediate values

Tags: python, dictionary

I'd like to map a value through a dictionary multiple times, and record the intermediate values. Since `list.append()` doesn't return a value, below is the best I've been able to come up with. Is there a better way to do this in Python, perhaps using a list comprehension or recursion?

```
def append(v, seq):
    seq.append(v)
    return v

def multimap(value, f, count):
    result = []
    for _ in range(count):
        value = append(f[value], result)

    return result

print( multimap('a', {'a': 'b', 'b': 'c', 'c': 'd', 'd': 'a'}, 4) )
```

Output:

```
['b', 'c', 'd', 'a']
```

Comment: Are you on 2 or 3? It looks like itertools.accumulate could do this.

Comment: @user2357112: The question arose in the context of Py 3, but it would be fairly easy to write a simplified version of `accumulate` for version Py 2 (as I've done on occasion) — although @shx2's first answer below, which is very similar to that, would work in both versions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of having to deal with lists, you can simply use a generator:

```
def multimap(value, f, count):
    for _ in range(count):
        value = f[value]
        yield value

print(list(multimap('a', {'a': 'b', 'b': 'c', 'c': 'd', 'd': 'a'}, 4)))
```

Comment: I like this approach...and making it a generator could come in useful in other more iterative contexts,

Answer (score 1):

You can also do this:

```
def multimap(val, f, count):
    result = []
    _ = [result.append(f[result[-1]] if result else f[val]) for _ in range(count)]
    return result


>>> multimap('a', {'a': 'b', 'b': 'c', 'c': 'd', 'd': 'a'}, 4)
['b', 'c', 'd', 'a']
```

But i don't think this counts as a python-esque solution.

Comment: Although there's a list comprehension involved, it's wasteful since it's executed only for its side-effects.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution, inspired by functional programming. This solution is recursive and utterly inefficient.

```
def multimap(value, f, count):
    if count <= 0:
        return []
    return [ f[value] ] + multimap(f[value], f, count - 1)
```

Comment: +1 for elegance and potential one-liner-ness: `return [f[value]] + multimap(f[value], f, count-1) if count > 0 else []`. Too bad about the inefficiency...

Answer (score 1):

Not long after I posted my question and left for a while to grab a byte to eat, I thought of one answer that's different from all the others posted thus far...and after a little optimization is, aside from some initialization, relatively simple.

One of the arguments to the function is `count`, which makes it possible to partially initialize the resulting list in advance, eliminating the need to build it up incrementally with multiple `append` calls:

```
def multimap(value, f, count):
    result = [] if count < 1 else [f[value]] + [None]*(count-1)
    for i in range(1, count):
        result[i] = f[result[i-1]]
    return result
```